# Markdown preview Python-based plugin for gedit

Tags: python, gedit

I've installed the [markdown preview plugin](http://www.jpfleury.net/en/software/gedit-markdown.php) for gedit running on Lubuntu 13.04. It works as expected.

[image: markdown preview in gedit]

However, for ease of viewing, I altered the appearance of the resulting html panel (left panel) by including a link to a local stylesheet at the top of each markdown file. But this approach obviously means that I have to alter all my existing markdown files.

To avoid that, I looked at `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/markdown-preview/__init__.py` which has the [code for the plugin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5938766/), and I see lines #39 and #40 (reproduced below):

```
# Can be used to add default HTML code (e.g. default header section with CSS).
htmlTemplate = "%s"
```

That gives me the impression that I can somehow tell the plugin to look at a stylesheet and style the html accordingly. But I don't know what to do (if indeed `htmlTemplate = "%s"` has to be changed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `htmlTemplate` to something like the following

```
# Can be used to add default HTML code (e.g. default header section with CSS).
htmlTemplate = """
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" media="screen" href="http://paste.ubuntu.com/static/pastebin.css">
</head>
<body>
%s
</body>
</html>
"""
```

Comment: Your code (as modified above) works perfectly but please could you explain why you've used `"""` instead of `'''`? Both work for me.

Comment: Multi-line strings can either use """ or '''. Look at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings